# timing javascript and src changes?

Tags: javascript, delay, src

ok so i have this javascript to use the arrow keys to send these javascripts when i press arrowkeys. i have a collaborating script that makes the right('img') command move the image but im trying to change the image as it moves with src changes and delays. Help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;       
function KeyCheck(event) {

  var spacebar=32
  var KeyID = event.keyCode;
  switch(KeyID) {

      case 39:
        right('img'); 
        document.getElementById('img').src = 'guyr.png';
        setTimeout("right('img'); 
        document.getElementById('img').src = 'runr.png'; 
        setTimeout("right('img'); 
        document.getElementById('img').src = 'guyr.png';",100);",100);
      break;

   }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I cleaned up your code a bit. To second @Sime, you may want to revisit your code.

Comment: @Tom The code is still broken. You cannot span string in multiple lines. The above code will produce an error in your browser.

Comment: @Tom I've corrected the code. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/pSjqJ/

Comment: thanks @Tom, but that was just an excerpt, there is also a left case and an up and down case the left and right are the only ones with the need for src changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do some sort of a game or animation, try to read a little about it, how to structure your game loop, animations and etc.

But if you are doing just some sort of test try something like this, is not a beautiful code but the idea of an animation should work:

```
document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;

function KeyCheck(event) {

    var spacebar = 32;
    var KeyID = event.keyCode;

    switch (KeyID) {

    case 39:

        function guy(fn) {
            right('img');
            document.getElementById('img').src = 'guyr.png';
            setTimeout(function() {
                fn(guy);
            }, 100);
        }
        function run(fn) {
            right('img');
            document.getElementById('img').src = 'runr.png';
            setTimeout(function() {
                fn(run);
            }, 100);
        }

        guy(run);

        break;
    }

}
```

One function calls another, receiving it by parameter, in order to to continue the animation.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `src` attribute of an image is going to trigger an asynchronous GET request, and may be slow at first before the browser has cached the images. It looks like you are implementing a game of some sort? Instead of changing the `src` of a single image, I would keep all of the images hidden initially, and toggle the `visibility` CSS attribute of images you want to show/hide. That way, you can pre-fetch all of the images that you'll need during load time, and simply show/hide elements as the handlers for your `onkeydown` events.

Comment: You could also use CSS Sprites, look them up!

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do this, including several UI frameworks that will greatly help you out.

Comment: Indeed! Sprites are used a *lot* in game making (assuming you are making a game).

Comment: well i can send you the code, to learn javascript i set out on a project to make an all html/javascript website that lets a man move by your arrow keys but just having an image of a guy move wasn't that great so i tried to make him run.